# Prevent favorites folders from expanding

Tags: phpstorm

My "problem" is that favorites auto expand whenever a file that is in that favorites list gets changed. For example I have a file financials.php inside the favorites list "bike lockers" and whenever I change that file it expands the "bike lockers" list. Is there a way to change it so the favorites folder does not expand when one of the files that it contains gets modified?

[image]

Comment: looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129229, please follow it for updates

Comment: @lena: thank you! I see it's been 6 years so i don't think it will be solved anytime soon :(